# Create generic service class in java for reading the collection from mongodb

Tags: java, json, mongodb, generics

Everyone, I want to create a service class(a very generic) in java which will accept all the required parameters for reading a collection from MongoDb. and return JSON string as result.

Comment: That's not a very constructive "question". If you want help, please show some effort.

Comment: @NilsH go back to work! ;)

Comment: @ Nilsh, you were right, but i was posting the answer too!. and this is kind of handy way to design a service which can read any type of collection with sort and basic search predicates.

Comment: @priyankjain I see that now. I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the quick guide to do this.

Prerequisite: Java driver for mongodb. Basic knowledge of MongoDb.

Assumption:

1. All the required parameters are passed for reading the collection from mongoDB.

here is a quick list of required params.

serverNameUrl - This is the path of server where mongodb is running, for e.g. "localhost"

dbName - Name of the Database. say "University" database.

collectionName - Name of the collection.

fieldValuePair - Here we are recviing the Field Values in a String form with two seaprators(: ,). say we want **'Name','Empno','Dept'** of all employee whose 'Dept=ABC'. then this value would be "**Name,Empno,Dept:ABC**".

fVSeaprator- this seaprator string used for field and value, here it is ":".

vFSeaprator- this seaprator string used in between fields here it is ",".

sortField- Sortfield. Say empno

sortDirection- Sortdirection Say "-1" DESC(default is DESC).

here is the code for same!.

```
package com.service.mongo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;
import com.xp.util.Utils;

public class TestGenericService {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Start. This return a JSON string.
    String result =readQueryOfMongo("localhost","test","employeeCollection","Name,Empno,Dept:ABC",":",",","Empno","");
    System.out.println(result);
}


public static String readQueryOfMongo(  

        String serverNameUrl ,
        String dbName ,
        String collectionName,
        String fieldValuePair,
        String fVSeaprator,
        String vFSeaprator,
        String sortField,
        String sortDirection
)
{
    DB db;
    DBCollection table = null;
    DBCursor cursor = null;
    String result=null;
    BasicDBObject sortPredicate = new BasicDBObject();
    try
    {

        Map<String, String> fieldValuePairMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        System.out.println("ServerName:"+serverNameUrl+"\nDatabase Name:"+dbName+"\nCollection Name:"+collectionName);

        //Configure the server, db and collection.
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( serverNameUrl );

        db = mongoClient.getDB( dbName );

        System.out.println(db.getLastError());

        if (db.collectionExists(collectionName))
        {
            table = db.getCollection(collectionName);

        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Collection doesn't exist");
        }

        //Define SortPredicate.
        if(sortField!= null)
        {
            if(sortDirection==null ||sortDirection.trim().length()==0)
                sortDirection="-1";//Default sort-order should be DESC.

            sortPredicate.put(sortField, Integer.parseInt(sortDirection));
        }

        if (null != fieldValuePair && fieldValuePair.trim().length() > 0)

        {
            BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();

            fieldValuePairMap = parseStringToMap(fieldValuePair, fVSeaprator, vFSeaprator);

            System.out.println(fieldValuePairMap.size());

            BasicDBObject fields1 = new BasicDBObject("_id",false);


            if(fieldValuePairMap.size()>0)
            {
                Set keySet  = fieldValuePairMap.keySet();
                Iterator keyIter = keySet.iterator();
                String tempKey;
                while (keyIter.hasNext()) 
                {
                    tempKey = keyIter.next().toString();
                    fields1.append(tempKey, true);
                    if(fieldValuePairMap.get(tempKey)!=null)
                        searchQuery.put(tempKey, fieldValuePairMap.get(tempKey));
                }

                cursor = table.find(searchQuery,fields1).sort(sortPredicate);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            cursor = table.find().sort(sortPredicate);
        }
        result = parseStubJson(cursor, collectionName);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return result;
}

public static String parseStubJson(DBCursor dBCursor, String stubName)
{
    System.out.println("Creating a JSON stub of:"+stubName);

    String response="{"+"\""+stubName+"\":[";
    int i=0;
    int j= dBCursor.count();
    while (dBCursor.hasNext()) 
    {
        i++;
        response += JSON.parse(dBCursor.next().toString());
        if(j>i)
            response +=",";
    }

    response += "]}";
    return response;
}

public static Map<String, String>  parseStringToMap(String kerValuePair,String seprator1,String seprator2)
{
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String[] pairs = kerValuePair.split(seprator2);
    for (int i=0;i<pairs.length;i++) {
        String pair = pairs[i];
        String[] keyValue = pair.split(seprator1);
        if(keyValue.length > 1)
            myMap.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
        else
            myMap.put(pairs[i], null);
    }

    Iterator itr = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Object object = (Object) itr.next();
        System.out.println(object.toString());
    }
    return myMap;
}
```

}

Note: This above code returns result in JSON string form, You can use any parser at client end and convert the result in required list or stub.
Yes, you may feel that the above example is written with SQL mindset, and this is not the best use of NOSQL (mongodb), but to understand basic read operation in mongodb this is very much useful.